# Flutter: Kotlin Gradle plugin version

Tags: flutter, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I faced an issue with the Android kotlin version. I used  `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'`. However, it's showing me this type error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':platform_device_id' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              9.7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this error seens [platform_device_id] plugin support android and kotlin version is so slow.

You can go to the pub and download platform_device_id plugin the change the [ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'] as [ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.20'] in [Downloads/platform_device_id-1.0.1/android/build.gradle].

download url:
https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/platform_device_id/versions

Then use path way depandences [platform_device_id] plugin, such as:

```
platform_device_id: 
  path: plugin/platform_device_id
```

Then move [platform_device_id-1.0.1] to plugin folder in you project and change name as [platform_device_id].

Answer (score 0):

So, if I download the code and open it in Android Studio and search "kotlin-gradle-plugin" I can find it in "ios/.symlinks/plugins/platform_device_id/android/build.gradle"

When I change ext.kotlin_version in that file to "1.5.20", the build works.

I have no idea what that file is or how to change this value so I can build and deploy from within FlutterFlow.

source:

https://community.flutterflow.io/troubleshooting/post/build-fails-android-gradle-vs-kotlin-gradle-R2uuWLgAi9oc36t